Trying to get values from a spinner on Appium Inspector
Im trying to get a value from this spinner but I cant select it using Appium Inspector, but it only selects the thing below the item: Appium Inpector with the spinner not selected
List opened, and the select is on the thing below the list: Appium Inpector with the spinner selected
I did use the tap function to select it on my code, but I dont want to do that way, it feels kinda like a really lazy solution.
(I'm using python for my code btw)

no code as image. please put all your code in your question as plain text
